# Unit testing Angular with Karma/Jasmine:

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have inserted an if-else condition in my component so that after login I will be forwarded to a specific URL. However, my unit test now fails with the following error:

> 1) should create
>
> AnotherComponent
>
> ```
>  Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'testroute'
> ```

Without the if else condition everything is working fine, so I'm sure that this is the cause of my problem. The funny thing is, that I'm not testing anything that is related to the code inside my ngOnInit() lifecycle. More funny is, that not the test for MyComponent is failing but the test for another Component.

My Component (MyComponent) looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  routes = Constants.routes;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private myService: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.myService.context === 'TEST') {
      this.router.navigate([routes.testroute + this.myService.context]);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([routes.testroute]);
    }
  }
}
```

The Template looks like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The unit test of the failing component looks like this:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
      ],
      providers: [
        PathLocationStrategy
      ],
      declarations: [AnotherComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AnotherComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the route when you import the router testing module. I generally set routes up with dummy components.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
      // add routes here
      { path: 'testroute', component: DummyComponent }
    ]),
 ],
 providers: [
    PathLocationStrategy
  ],
 declarations: [AnotherComponent],
}).compileComponents();
```

```
@Component({ template: '' })
class DummyComponent { }
```